# HTTP get status of VLC player

Tags: javascript, xml, http, qml, vlc

So I am continuing my work on the VLC remote in QML and got quite a bit done I am able to controls most the basic functions now :) But I need to get the actual state of the player.

To send my commands I use the following code:

```
function passCommands(command)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest()
    var url = "http://" + ip + ":" + port + "/requests/status.xml?command=" + command;

    http.open("POST", url, true);

    // Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Qt.btoa(username + ":" + password));
    http.send();
}
```

What I want to do now is to get data from

```
http://192.168.2.2:8080/requests/status.xml
```

because that's how VLC player stores it's status and it looks something like this:

```
<root>
   <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
   <aspectratio>default</aspectratio>
   <audiodelay>0</audiodelay>
   <apiversion>3</apiversion>
   <currentplid>16</currentplid>
   <time>1</time>
   <volume>128</volume>
   <length>6450</length>
   <random>false</random>
```

So I am trying to access the the information in the status.xml I looked into XmlListModel but got very confused. 
Can my current function be re-writen to get the information I want out of the status.xml file?

Thanks

Comment: Just for clarity: You are trying to extract certain parts of information out of `status.xml`?

Comment: Yes, to find out what's the title of the media that user is player and the length so I could make a seek bar and get users preferences

Comment: So this really comes down to "how do I use XPath in QML?"